# Calculate the nth percentile height above sea level of a country or US State

Tags: geography, geographics

Mathematica has access to geographic height data for different territories. This can be used [to plot sea level rise maps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180356). However I am interested in what percentage of the area of a country or state is under a certain height above sea level. I thought about randomly sampling points in area of interest, however that seems inelegant and could also cause problems if I just sample the 2D projection, due to distortion.

Comment: Appropriate random sampling is never inelegant and probably should be considered more often.  How precise do you think you need to be and is the available data precise enough to meet that need?

Comment: The geographic height data Mathematica has just about as precise resolution as i need in the region i care about. Instead of Monte-Carlo integration classical integration would be prefered. A 0.1% percentile precision is good enough so $p(x-0.1\%) \leq p_{estimate}(x) \leq p(x+0.1\%)$

Comment: Appropriate random sampling is not restricted to Monte-Carlo integration (although the database must be constructed from discrete points so I'm not following where integration of a smooth surface comes directly into play).  If your desired approach doesn't work out, you might consult with a statistician.

Comment: There exists some interpolation Mathematica is using to display height information like this. One could $\int_A \text{if } h(x,y)\leq h_c \text{ then }1 \text{ else } 0 dxy$ over this interpolation one could get an really, really good estimate. This where integration might be an viable approach. Ideally one would use spherical coordinates.